# Date Formatter returns when using DateFormatter().date(from: String)

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, ios13, dateformatter

I have the following code:

```
//converting date into desired format
    let formatterGet = DateFormatter()
    formatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz" //"2014-09-21 21:00:00  0000"
    let date = formatterGet.date(from: birthday) 
    print(date)

    // "decoding" the new format to be shown in the UI
    let formatterShow = DateFormatter()
    formatterShow.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
    birthdayTextField.text = formatterShow.string(from: date ?? Date())
```

The problem is that when I print the date in the console, it shows nil every time. How can I fix it?

Comment: In your commented date you have 2 spaces between the time and the time zone. Is that a typo or is that what it is actually like?

Comment: Just to double check, are you sure `birthday` has the format in the comment “2014-09-21 21:00:00 0000”? Also, in the comment there is one double space between “21:00:00” and “0000”

Comment: @alxlives there are actually two spaces "21:00:00" and "0000", but before migrating to iOS13 it worked like that, and now it doesn't. I tried with two spaces but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Fogmeister There are in fact two spaces, but when i add them to the dateFormat string, it still returns nil.

Comment: The `zzzz` time zone specifier is wrong, I believe. Also, you should set locale to POSIX to prevent 12/24h time problems.

Comment: The `0000` cannot be decoded by any timezone specifier unless you add `+` or `-` sign. `zzzz` does not mean what you think it does. See https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @Sulthan What should i do? if I remove "zzzz" it doesn't work as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the string from the server ALWAYS end with two spaces and  `0000`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `DateFormatter` conversion. You have two options:

1: Removing the `zzzz` from the formatter and from the date:

```
    let birthday = "2014-09-21 21:00:00"
    let formatterGet = DateFormatter()
    formatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let date = formatterGet.date(from: birthday)

    print(date)
```

Output:

```
    Optional(2014-09-22 00:00:00 +0000)
```

2: Adding a `+` sign on the date:

```
   let birthday = "2014-09-21 21:00:00 +0000"
   let formatterGet = DateFormatter()
   formatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz"
   let date = formatterGet.date(from: birthday)

   print(date)
```

Output:

```
   Optional(2014-09-22 00:00:00 +0000)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to remove zzzz, but it doesn't work. Also, I cant add "+" to "0000", because it is returned from a server

Comment: @Nikkko "+0000" means UTC time. And yes add it back there. Don't remove it from your string `"2014-09-21 21:00:00 +0000"` and use date format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"`. Don't forget to set the date formatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` and if you need the other way around as well set the timezone to zero seconds from gmt

Comment: The problem is that the server date format is incompatible. If the server date can't be changed, have you considered replacing it on the front, like: `birthday = birthday.replacingOccurrences(of: " 0000", with: "+0000")` ?

Comment: @alxlives I ended up using your method, and as of now, it work great for me. Thank you very much!!

Comment: If the server date string always ends with two spaces and `0000` then use `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss  0000"` for the date format.

Comment: I should add that if you use that date format, be sure to get the date formatter's timezone to UTC time or you will get the wrong time in the resulting date.